# What makes a question show up on the homepage?

Tags: support

Earlier I noticed this on the homepage:

[image]

That's [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250681/changed-flash-drives-mount-point-now-i-cant-mount-anything) I asked at the beginning of the month, but someone else's name is next to it. At first I thought they answered or edited it, but it doesn't look like they did. So...why is it there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have the right idea that if someone **answers** or **edits** a post, the question gets bumped to the front page. And that's exactly what had happened. Someone added an "answer" and I then deleted it on the grounds that it doesn't answer the question. (It was a "me too" post.)

Since they made a post on the question, their name is on the question now. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It does; thanks.

Comment: Good Moderation, sir!

Comment: A free bump, awwwww yeah!