# Duplicate Questions Still Show Up?

Tags: support, duplicates

I've read the answer listed [here,](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6204/what-makes-a-question-show-up-on-the-homepage) but I still have a few questions. When a question is marked duplicate, it is marked with **[Duplicate]**, but what does that do? (For reference check [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729577/linux-newbie-wanting-to-become-a-linux-master)) The question is marked as **[Duplicate]**, and no ***Answers*** can be added, but other than that, no changes are made. Edits can still be made, comments can be added, and votes can still be made. I have seen questions that have been marked duplicate that quickly disappear and I guess my question is why some of these questions stay on the homepage for an extended period of time instead of just getting closed permanently

Comment: ☑ ??? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your definition of "closed permanently", but before being actually **closed** any question gets put **on hold** first, to allow the OP to edit, change, ... its question to allow it to be clarified *as it might not be off-topic/duplicate/...*

After the 7-day grace period of **on hold**, the question gets closed and after a number of months of inactivity, soft deleted. (Nothing ever gets deleted: it still stays in SE's database forever)

*However* a duplicate question is a special case as it acts like a pointer towards another question.  So sometimes the duplicate generates more initial views then the original and deleting the duplicate from the site would be counter-productive as otherwise someone else might ask the exact same duplicate.

Just to give a hypothetical example: "How does hibernation work?" might be a good question with an excellent answer, but "My hibernation doesn't work!" is a duplicate of the former and unfortunately, that's what most people type in google, so they get re-directed to the correct answer!

### ;-)